# Zookeeper - cant telnet into xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 2181 on one server. Any other - no issue

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

I have three zookeeper nodes in tokyo, london, and freemont on linode servers. All are gossiping.

I have a monitoring server in tokyo.

I have NOT activated the zookeeper firewall on all zookeeper servers.

From my local dev laptop, aws, etc machine I can telnet into anyone of the zookeeper nodes.

From linode, monitoring server, I cant connect by using any client.

I did use UFW to block incoming ports on the monitoring server but I dont see
how that is causing issues with zookeeper port.  I even disable as well to avail.

From the monitoring server I get nothing.

```
telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 2181

Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

using mtr --report from both ends shows no issues.

So, I cant connect to zookeeper from a server.  How do I find out what is going on?

Comment: Do the logs on that ZK server say anything? Also check if there are established connections from the monitoring server's IP -- ZK limits the number of simultaneous connections from a single IP.

Comment: Oh....on the monitoring server, I am checking stuff in a while loop.  Basically hitting the servers constantly.  Can that be changed?  Nothing in the logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But you *are* connected:

```
Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.
```

Whether or not you get any initial communication from the server you're connecting to (a la SSH or SMTP) or the server is waiting for the client to start (HTTP) is a protocol specific issue.  However the problem is (almost) certainly not a firewalling problem.

Comment: Yeah..I dont think is a FF as well.  again mtr shows no issue